# request.user not being populated by my django auth backend

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication, django-users

I have written a authorization backend class that implements a `authenticate` method and a `get_user` method as per the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend). I've added

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('src.lib.auth_backend.MyBackend',)
```

to my settings.py file. Through print statements I can see that my code is being run and that it is returning a user object of the class I defined with `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in my settings.py.

By the time I get the request object within my django-rest-framework `has_object_permsion` function, `request.user` is always set to `AnonymousUser`.

Am I missing a step? 
I've tried this with and without `django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware` installed and get the same outcome.

This failure is happening in the following unit test

```
def test_get_user(self):
    client = APIClient() # rest_framework.test.APIClient
    client.login(username='user1',password='user1Password')
    res = client.get('/websvc/users/' + str(user.user_id) + '/') # request.user will be AnonymousUser
    self.assertEqual(res.status_code, 200) # it will be 403, which is appropriate for AnonymousUser
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things may be wrong.

Have you created the user, before runnign the test?

What returns `client.login`?

Show us the whole test, to tell you what's wrong.